# ArcPy not reading Layer properly?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.6, count

I would like to work with selections. For that I start to read the layer from a mxd. I have controlled that the layer count 0 returns the correct name, but the GetCount_management is empty as is the following selection. I have never used the GetCount_management before, it is just a step I added before my selection to check why I do not get data returned. The layer is a shape and definitely not empty. It is the first script that I start in 10.6.1

```
Stationer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)[0]
print Stationer.name
print arcpy.GetCount_management(Stationer)
```

Comment: try this : print arcpy.GetCount_management(Stationer)[0]

Comment: still 0. It is as I have written also just a debugging-step. The later selection of features is simply empty. I first thought that I made a mistake there, but it seems that the way I have been reading layers in in 10.5 is not working in 10.6.1 One thing that I can try is to test an old script.

Comment: Is your Stationer layer in a group layer? You are returning the first layer from a list which could potentially be another layer or a group layer, also verify that you mxd object is valid too. Also look at the help file for get count tool! Look at the code samples at the end of the page, see how they return the count, you are not following the same method.

Comment: It might sit outside environment extent.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. There was either something with the mxd or the shp not the script. I have made a copy of the data & loaded them into a new mxd, now it is working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solved his/her problem but I think the question and the answer added by OP are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`arcpy.GetCount_management(Stationer)[0]` returning `0` can mean one of two things:

1. The layer's feature class contains no features.
2. A selection was applied to the layer that returned no selected features.

1 isn't the case, so I can only assume it's 2. Try [clearing the selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) of your layer prior to proceeding.

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (Stationer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")`